# PMOD I2S2 bit resolution

Tags: fpga

Im getting a bit confused about the bit resolution I should use with I2S2 Pmod.

It says the max resolution its 24 bit per sample (24 for left audio and 24 for right audio)

But then, they recommend the bit clock toggle 64 times each audio sample (32 times left audio and 32 times right audio), so the resolution would be 32 bit.

Can someone explain me this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: 24 BIT RESOLUTION]

[image: Here it says the bit frequency should be 64x the sample rate]

Comment: The Digilent [Pmod I2S2 Reference Manual](https://digilent.com/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/reference-manual) contains "The Digilent Pmod I2S2 (Revision A) features a [Cirrus CS5343 Multi-Bit Audio A/D Converter](https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs5343-44/) and a [Cirrus CS4344 Stereo D/A Converter](https://www.cirrus.com/products/cs4344-45-48/), each connected to one of two audio jacks." Those Cirrus devices say "Discontinued Product" on their web pages. Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/695695/edit) to include which devices are used on your "I2S2 Pmod".

Answer (score 0):

No, the resolution is not 32 bits even if the sample slot is 32 bits but the chip uses only 24 bits out of the 32 bits available.

You need to find what chip the module uses and read the chip data sheet for details.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone gets thinking about this, I ve found an explanation, on the documentation it says the first falling edge of the bit clock will not count, and after that one, it will start sampling.

So bit 63 wont count, then bits from 62 to 39 will be the left audio data, and then form bit 30 to 7 will be the right audio data.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: No it isn't actually.

Comment: Yeah it is, I have checked it

Comment: That is standard working of I2S. While interesting how I2S works, it does not answer your question. So not useful. This chip just works with 32-bit slots or 64 bits per two samples. It's still a 24-bit converter and does not work with 48 bits per two samples, even if other converters might.

Comment: What I was wondering was where the 24 useful bits where among the 32 bit slots, that was what I couldnt understand properly, I think I explained it on a good way.